# How to add a waypoint in draw.io

Tags: draw.io

All the instructions, support pages and general places I search mention this:

right click on a connector and select "Add Waypoint". All support requests are maximum about how to remove accidentally added waypoints. That would be great to achieve for me, then no matter how often I do the steps right click on the connector and select "Add Waypoint", there is literally every time zero new waypoints added.

What's wrong here? Can somebody please elaborate?

Further, I use an existing template and in this template, new connectors somehow can be over each other and not resemble a "fat" line or just looks like one line. If I do it, it becomes fat or visibly two lines always only.

It looks to me like an unsolvable problem atm and I'm close to give up with draw.io before I even really started because for me super super basic functions are far from even being remotely working.

So any help would be really appreciated, losing my mind here over this.

See above

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same issue in other browsers and Incognito mode, you can attach a diagram and video showing all the steps related to waypoints and connectors to support@diagrams.net or https://groups.google.com/g/drawio